# C# Xpath not correct when the xpath contains text()

Tags: c#, xpath, html-agility-pack

Let me keep it simple i was trying to get the release date. when i get the xpath i get a text() on the end it just doesn't work. here is a what i am trying to get.

This is just part of the website code i am pasting the whole code is 5000 lines.
here is a link http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2561572/?ref_=nm_knf_t3 if you right click on the release date inspect it and then copy the xpath it does not work in c#.

```
<span class="ghost">|</span>
<a href="/title/tt2561572/releaseinfo?ref_=tt_ov_inf"
title="See more release dates" >7 May 2015 (Netherlands)
<meta itemprop="datePublished" content="2015-05-07" />
```

I know the format is not good but best is if you take any movie on IMDB just the release date that is what i am trying to get. the release date 7 May 2015. and the meta content attribute. i cant seem to find out why it wont happen here is my code.

this was my first try it did not work. it sees the node but when i add Text() it just does not work

```
            // Loading and getting the document
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = base.Document;

            // Getting the node
            HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id=\"title - overview - widget\"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/di‌​v[2]/div/a[3]/text()");

            // Retuning the text of the node
            return node.InnerText;
```

then i started trying to get the content values out of the meta. i also want also did not work

```
// Getting the node
HtmlNode node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id=\"title - overview - widget\"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/a[4]/meta");

string date = node.Attributes["content"].Value;
```

This is when i was tried to get the Meta line. but when you get the 7 may 2015 xpath it ends with text() and it just does not work. And i know i am posting a lot sorry for that.

Comment: We can't see your HTML, so it's hard to know why your XPath is wrong... it also doesn't help that you've only described it as "just does not work" rather than saying what actually happens.

Comment: This is the xpath //*[@id="title-overview-widget"]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/a[3]/text()

Comment: Well that's not the XPath that's in your question, so I'm not sure what it *is*... but that's not what I asked, either. I asked for the HTML you're looking for the data in, as well as what actually happens.

Comment: @kevindt12 please read [MCVE] carefully and [edit] the question accordingly.

Comment: There maybe now better

Comment: i tried everyting.

Comment: Oh some helpfull info doesn not work i mean null exception

Comment: No one anymore?

Comment: OKay so no more help

Answer (score 0):

Got it thanks that no one helped. the xpath sould be //div[@class='subtext']//meta[@itemprop=\"datePublished\"]"